# "Nein" vs "nee", is there any difference?

Tags: slang, standard-german, spoken-language

The only time I've ever seen Germans say *nein* is in the movies or in textbooks. I've also heard a politician say *nein* when she wanted to make a strong stand again a comment. I'm guessing *nein* is more forceful and formal language than *nee*, which seems to be slang.

So I'm guessing if I don't want my language to seem weird I should use *nee* to negate a sentence and not *nein*, especially with younger people and in casual settings like a bar. Or is my impression wrong?

Answer (score 23):

If you want to learn German, then you learn standard German, which will be understood in all countries where German is spoken. But »nee« is not a standard-German word. It is a dialect word. »Nee« is part of many dialects, spoken mainly in mid and northern parts of Germany. But there are also German dialects, where »nein« is another word:

[image]
See also [here](https://www.philhist.uni-augsburg.de/lehrstuehle/germanistik/sprachwissenschaft/ada/runde_1/f10/).

If you really want to learn one of the many German dialects, you better should learn standard German before. So do not replace »nein« by »nee«. Everybody will understand you if you say »nein«. And even if you say »nee« in a region where people use this word: Nobody will believe, that you really speak the local dialect as long as you have any non-German accent.

Comment: Sidenote, perhaps a tad off-topic. _Nee_ (pronounced _nay_) is the Dutch translation of _nein_. It would not surprise me if this has had influence on the dialect's regional spread.

Comment: I never thought of _nee_ and _nö_ excluding each other. Then there’s _nä_ or _ne_, a less emphatic variant with short vowel.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter The distribution of *nee*  is very similar to the distribution of Low German (closely related to Dutch) and Central German dialects. *nee*  is *nein* in Low German.

Comment: In general, *nee* is not a dialect word but a colloquial word. Otherwise, I wholeheartedly agree.

Comment: @Jan: What exactly is the difference between a colloquial word and a dialect word?

Comment: Schwer zu sagen, außer dass »ich es weiß, wenn ich es sehe.« *Hennaschregga* (Moped) ist eher ein Dialektwort, weil es nur von Leuten verwendet wird, die mehr Dialekt reden; und wenn es jemand verwendet, dessen Umgangssprache näher am Standard ist, wird er womöglich nicht verstanden. *Nix* würde ich eher der Umgangssprache zurechnen, denn auch Leute mit Aussprache näher zum Standard verwenden es, ohne dass es missverstanden werden könnte. In diese Kategorie gehört *nee* meines Erachtens eher.

Comment: @Jan Ich würde "Hühnerschreck" eher als etwas antiquierten Kolloquialismus bezeichnen.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: dialects are regional variants (as opposed to 'standard' language), whereas colloquialisms are phenomena that occur in spoken language (as opposed to written language). Awesome map btw!

Comment: @ParaDice The "Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache" (the map's source) has now moved here: http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de

Comment: Beware of "noh": it is used in Thüringen (see e. g. http://www.juma-thueringen.de/2014/11/erfurt-noh/) and means "yes", even though it looks and sounds just like another variant of nein/nee/naa/noi/... same for "nu" in Sachsen (http://www.sachsenwelt.de/sachsen/mundart/woerterbuch-a.html#N)

Answer (score 8):

“Nee” is not slang, it's simply dialect. This form of “nein” occurs in more than one, but definitely not in all German dialects.

I am from Berlin, and even though I do not speak a real Berlin dialect, saying “nee” is one of these things that happen when I speak sloppily, but not in all instances, so I say “nein” often enough and would not find it in any way strange if someone else uses it, especially not if German is not that person's first language.

Comment: »*This form of “nein” occurs in more than one, but definitely not in all German dialects.*« Correct. In Bavaria and Austria it is »Naa« (long a). But you can also hear »nee« in those regions, especially among young urban people.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, interesting, I had not noticed the use of “nee” when I was in the south. It probably seemed to natural for me to notice.

Comment: The group of people using »nee« in Austria is small, but it exists. You find them among people under the age of 20/25.

Answer (score 3):

I would have said "nee", but it has to be 30 characters, so:

No, there is no difference. only that "nee" is slightly more slang. You wouldn't use it in an official paper.

While others have stated it is dialect, I personally would say that saying "nee" is acceptable and will be **understood in every** German-speaking region, it may just not be the most **common** way of abbreviating "nein".

Comment: Only because it's kind of a pun, I'm not going to vote for deleting this answer. Other than that, it doesn't add anything which hasn't already been said.

Answer (score 1):

I speak little German and understand far less spoken German but I did spend a few months in Koblenz. I almost immediately adopted "nee" because it just sounded so much more polite after hearing it a few times.

Comment: This is a perfect example of "when in Rome." Connotations for the same word can also change by region, so it's good to follow by example and talk to many different kinds of locals.

Answer (score 1):

My mother is from Lübeck. *Nee* is used when correcting a thought or speech the way Americans say, “bring me one, no, *two* beers” or if someone says something and you are correcting them. *Nein* is used if you want something or did something or against an action “I want to go somewhere” Nein!

*Nein* is final, while *nee* is arguable.

Comment: I cannot agree with your perceived difference. I have heard both *nee* and *nein* in all contexts. However, I cannot rule out that what you describe is specific to just Lübeck (where I haven’t spent enough time with locals to know).

Comment: I think this is less of a hard rule and more of a correlation. When people want to sound final, they tend to use more formal language (to show that they are serious) compared to when they are just joking or speaking their thoughts out loud. Similar to the usage of nicknames vs. full names.

Answer (score 1):

I am a journalist and native German.
NEIN is the official word for "no". Therfore you should always use it for formal exchanges/ official purposes. Also use it in private conversations when ist gets serious/ you want to make a clear statement.
Nee, nö...  is pure slang and dialect used in the northern regions, like Hamburg where I come from. Yet every German will understand it - just like
na, noi... slang/ dialect that´s more used in the southern parts

Answer (score 0):

I usually use "nein" only if I want to make sure the other person gets the answer right (and there is not much context, mimic and gesture involved). Any situation in which a misunderstanding would force the person to ask again. E.g. at the city administration or at the counter of the supermarket when people have to ask me if I have a paypack card.

Comment: I'm curious: In which situations don't you want to make sure the other person gets the answer right? Why do you even answer in such cases?

Comment: Well if the context, the gesture, the mimic already say "no" very clearly, it's not so important that the word that come out of my mouth has to be understood. Anything with an "n" would be enought.

Answer (score 0):

I am native German (with Swabian / south-western-German dialect). Usually I use several forms of saying "no": "Nein, danke" when declining an offer, but in general I am switching between "Nö", "Nee", "Nein" or "Noi" unconsiuosly depending on mood and situation, whereas the latter "Noi" I may mostly use when I am among other Swabians.

I think that all of these variants are generally understood by Germans, but when talking to someone from an other region of Germany, the Swabian "Noi" might be considered as inappropriate - like "He is so uneducated, he can't get over his rural dialect".