# Was genau unterscheidet einen Dialekt von Umgangssprache?

Tags: meaning, dialect, terminology

In einem Kommentar zu einer [anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/27551/1487) wurde behauptet, das Wort »nee« sei kein Dialektwort, sondern ein Wort der Umgangssprache. Ich sehe das anders, erkenne aber, dass die Antwort auf diese Frage sehr eng mit den Definitionen der Begriffe »Dialekt« und »Umgangssprache« zusammenhängt.

Daher frage ich nun nach den Definitionen dieser beiden Begriffe (insbesondere im Kontext der deutschen Sprache), wobei mich besonders die Abgrenzung der beiden Begriffe voneinander interessiert.

Ich persönlich würde die Trennung anhand der Grammatik vornehmen. Wenn diese (bis auf kleinere Ausnahmen) mit der Grammatik der Standardsprache übereinstimmt, würde ich von einer Umgangssprache sprechen, auch wenn die Aussprache eine andere ist, und wenn einige andere Vokabel verwendet werden.

Von einem Dialekt würde ich sprechen, wenn auch die Grammatik deutlich von der Grammatik der Standardsprache abweicht.

Diese Definitionen erlauben leider aber nicht, ein einzelnes Wort (wie eben z.B. »nee« oder eine andere Variante von »nein«) einer der beiden Klassen zuzuordnen, denn es ist ja keineswegs ausgeschlossen, dass ein und dasselbe Wort in vielen verschiedenen lokalen Dialekten verwendet wird. Daher wäre eine Definition, die nicht auf der Grammatik fußt, eventuell hilfreicher.

Comment: Oh, das wird schwierig, weil _Umgangssprache_ ein ziemlich schwammiger Begriff ist.

Comment: Der Wikipediaartikel zu Umgangssprache ist interessant: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umgangssprache

Comment: Der Übergang ist sicher fließend, aber es wird wohl auch auf die Aussprache ankommen. Umgangssprache sehe ich dabei primär als Gegensatz zur Schriftsprache. Das inkludiert auch umgangssprachliche Ausdrücke. Wenn wir zB vom "Pickerl" sprechen, oder, wie weiland Fischler, dass wir "die Krot schlucken müssen", dann ist das mE umgangssprachlich, aber nicht Dialekt.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ein [Dialekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialekt) ist eine regional begrenzte Variation der Standardsprache. Z.B. bayrisch, schwäbisch, Berliner Schnauze, etc. sind Dialekte.

Umgangssprache ist in der Tat ein sehr schwammiger Begriff. Nach meiner Erfahrung verwenden Nichtlinguisten ihn meistens in Abgrenzung zu einer "gepflegten Ausdrucksweise" bzw. zu dem, was man Deutschlernern in Deutschkursen beibringt, oder zu dem, was laut Duden "richtig" wäre.

Allgemein können sowohl Dialekte als auch [Soziolekte](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soziolekt) sich gegenüber der Standardsprache in Teilen der Grammatik, des Vokabulars und der Aussprache unterscheiden. Es kommt für eine Charakterisierung also nicht darauf an, in welchen Bereichen oder wie stark sich eine Sub-Sprache von der Standardsprache unterscheidet, sondern eher darauf, wo und unter welchen Umständen die betreffende Sub-Sprache verwendet wird.

Comment: Willkommen auf dem Stack Exchange zur deutschen Sprache und vielen Dank für Deine Antwort. Wenn Du Hilfe benötigst, schau mal in die [tour] oder den [help], oder komm im Chat vorbei. Viel Spaß!

Comment: Es macht immer wieder Freude, diese Art Erstlingsbeitrag zu lesen =3

Comment: Dialekte (im traditionellen Sinn) sind eben gerade nicht Variationen «der Standardsprache»!

Answer (score 2):

"Umgangssprache" ist für mich im Wesentlichen verschliffenes Hochdeutsch, angereichert mit lexikalischen und grammatikalischen Eigenheiten aus Dialekten, meist lokal unterschiedlich, ohne dass diese jedoch dominieren. Dem Umgangssprecher mag mal ein "dem sein", "größer wie" rausrutschen. Einige Formen mögen dann aus dem Dialekt über die Vorhalle Umgangssprache Eingang in die Hochsprache finden, so wie es etwa an dem am-Progressiv zu beobachten ist.

Ein Dialekt hingegen ist eine Sprache mit einer teilweise eigenständigen Grammatik und einem eigenen Vokabular. Der Dialektsprecher sagt also regelmäßig "dem sein" und nicht nur als "Fehler"; für ihn ist das richtig.

Answer (score 0):

Dialekt *ist* i.A. Umgangssprache (weil er eben keine Schriftsprache ist...), aber nicht umgekehrt - Also eher Unter-/Oberbegriff.