# Verbreitung des Adverbs »ur«

Tags: adverb, regional

In Österreich wird in der Umgangssprache schon sehr lange die Vorsilbe »*ur-*« verwendet, um den Ausdruck von Adjektive zu verstärken:

> Das Kleid ist **ur**schön.
>   Mir ist **ur**langweilig.
>   Das Moped ist **ur**schnell um die Kurve gekommen.

Dieses an Adjektive angefügte Präfix ist mir schon aus meiner Kindheit in Erinnerung und lässt sich mit Aufnahmen aus archivierten Interviews aus den 1970er-Jahren belegen. Es mag vielleicht aus einer Jugendsprache entstanden sein, wird heute aber in allen Altersgruppen verwendet.

Neuerdings bemerke ich, dass sich diese Silbe auch zu einem eigenständigen Wort verselbständigt hat, das als Adverb verwendet wird. Die Bedeutung ist dieselbe geblieben und entspricht ungefähr dem Wort »sehr«, wenn auch mit deutlich mehr Nachdruck. So las ich z.B. heute in einem Facebook-Postings diesen Satz (gekürzt):

> Zwei Damen haben sich **ur** aufgeregt.

Dieser Satz ist Teil einer Kampagne, mit der ein Grafiker für ein von ihm entworfenes Plakat wirbt.

In einer bereits drei Jahre alten Parodie wird dem damaligen österreichischen Bundeskanzler Werner Faymann dieser Satz in den Mund gelegt:

> Das freut mich **ur**.

(Quelle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oEQNe_dpftQ bei ca. 2:48)

Das Adverb »*ur*« wird in Österreich ganz eindeutig nicht als Teil der Standardsprache wahrgenommen, sondern als ein Vokabel der Umgangssprache. Für die Vorsilbe *ur-* trifft das im Wesentlichen ebenfalls zu. Während man die Vorsilbe aber zumindest in Wien durchaus auch z.B. in einem seriösen geschäftlichen Gespräch mit einem Kunden verwenden kann, riskiert man als ungebildet zu gelten, wenn man das Adverb »ur« verwendet. (Davon ausgenommen ist ein ironischer Kontext.) Das Adverb »ur« wird daher fast ausschließlich bei informellen Gesprächen im Freundeskreis verwendet. Jedoch konnte ich es auch schon aus dem Mund von Akademikern hören, es ist also keineswegs auf Bevölkerungsschichten mit geringer formaler Bildung beschränkt, obwohl es, wie ich vermute, genau dort entstanden ist.

---

Meine Frage: Ist die Verwendung von »ur« als Adverb ein rein österreichisches Phänomen, oder ist »*ur*« als Adverb auch in anderen Regionen in Verwendung?

Comment: Ich würde es definitiv der Umgangssprache zuordnen, und zwar nicht nur in adverbialer Form. "Uroarg" oder "urfad" rollt irgendwie auch leichter von der Zunge als urarg und urlangweilig. "Ich hab' mich ur g'freut" würde ich (im Freundeskreis) sagen, "das freut mich ur" eher nicht.

Comment: Interessant. Dasselbe Phänomen tritt beim offenbar typisch schweizerischen (vgl. [Adj. huren « atlas-alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r8-f4q-2/)) Verstärkungswort *huere* auf. Man sagt: *Zwo Dame hei mi hueren ufgregt,* oder: *Das fröüt mi huere.*

Comment: @Ingmar: Die unzweifelhafte Zuordnung zur Umgangssprache habe ich ohnehin bereits sehr deutlich in der Frage außer Streit gestellt. »Uroarg« und »urfad« zähle ich übrigens eher zum Dialekt als zur Umgangssprache, wobei ich aber zugeben muss, das die Grenze zwischen beiden Begriffen äußerst unscharf ist (siehe http://german.stackexchange.com/q/27743/1487).

Comment: @mach: Interessant. Da keimt in mir die Frage auf, ob sich das schweizerische »hure« und das österreichische »ur« gegenseitig irgendwie beeinflusst haben.

Comment: @Hubert: Ich glaube nicht, dass sich diese Wörter gegenseitig beeinflusst haben. Solche indeklinablen Adjektive (es handelt sich nicht um Adverbien!) sind einfach eine grammatische Möglichkeit des Deutschen, egal ob sie nun wie *huere* denominal aus einem Substantiv gebildet sind oder wie *ur, mega* oder *super* aus einem Präfix.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Es wäre interessant wie weit `ur` überhaupt in Österreich verbreitet ist. Ich kenne `ur` erst seit ich in Wien wohne. Früher in Kärnten war es mir (bis auf die Wörter in @Thorstens Antwort) komplett unbekannt.

Comment: Im Nichtösterreichischen sind mir nur *urkomisch* und *urplötzlich* begegnet.

Comment: @raznagul es mit sämtlichen Adj. zu kombinieren, und es isoliert zu verwenden wie in "war es schön? - ja, ur!" ist typisch Wienerisch. scheint aber nach und nach in die umgebenden Bundesländer auszustrahlen.

Answer (score 4):

Ich habe festgestellt, dass *ur* in Österreich etwa den Stellenwert von *super* in Deutschland hat:

> Das Kleid ist **ur**schön
>   Das Kleid ist **super**schön

Im Deutschen gibt es *ur* auch, allerdings kenne ich es nur in Form des Adjektivs *urig* oder als Affix in Wörtern wie

- uralt
- urtümlich
- Urknall
- (unvollständige Liste - bitte gerne weitere Ausdrücke in den Kommentaren)

Nicht jedoch als "Steigerung" oder gar generell als Adverb. Es wird zum Beispiel verwendet, um auszudrücken, dass etwas der Beginn ("Ursprung") von etwas ist (z.B. Urknall, Urmensch) oder dass etwas einen hohen Grad einer Eigenschaft besitzt (z.B: urkomisch, uralt). Siehe dazu auch: https://www.dwds.de/wb/ur-

Comment: Affix ja, "Alter hervorheben" - nicht unbedingt. Siehe "urkomisch". Und die Antwort auf Huberts Frage lautet "ja".

Comment: Wie passt »urig« in die Liste? Ich glaube nämlich nicht, dass »ig« ein eigenständiges Wort ist, daher ist meiner Auffassung nach »ur« in diesem Fall auch kein Affix.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Da hast Du natürlich Recht. Das ist entstanden, weil ich ursprünglich das mit dem Affix nicht drinstehen hatte. Ich ändere das.

Comment: Ich kenne noch urplötzlich, ureigen.

Answer (score 2):

Ich bin ja nicht weit weg von Österreich im bayerisch-bairischen Sprachraum daheim (auf direktem Weg über Garmisch nach Scharnitz oder Ehrwald sind es ca. 70 km). Ich habe bisher keine dieser Verwendungen von *ur* gekannt.

An seine Stelle tritt (vor allem in der Jugendsprache) in meinem Teil Oberbayerns (sowie den benachbarten Gegenden in Schwaben) das Verstärkungsadverb *voll:*

> Das Kleid ist **voll** schön.
>
> Mir ist **voll** langweilig.
>
> Das Moped ist **voll** schnell um die Kurve gekommen.
>
> Zwei Damen haben sich **voll** aufgeregt.
>
> Das freut mich fei **voll.**

Sollte sich *ur* in der von dir angesprochenen Bedeutung in Deutschland überhaupt ausgebreitet haben, kommt aus meiner Sicht höchstens noch Südostbayern (Rosenheim, Traunstein, Mühldorf, Passau) in betracht. Mit Leuten aus dieser Gegend habe ich mich noch nicht ausführlich unterhalten, aber ein *ur* ist mir von ihnen auch noch nicht untergekommen.

Bis sich jemand aus diesem Bereich meldet und das Gegenteil behauptet, würde ich von einem rein österreichischen Phänomen ausgehen.

Comment: kleine Ergänzung zu *voll*: Ähnlich kann *ultra* verwendet werden.